# Illegal assignment: Cannot assign an unpacked type to a packed type

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

In SystemVerilog I wrote:

```
module mult32x32_arith (
    input logic clk,             // Clock
    input logic reset,           // Reset
    output logic [63:0] product  // Miltiplication product
);

logic left_decoder, right_decoder, product_FF[63:0]={64{1'b0}};

    always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
        if (reset==1'b1)begin
            product <= product_FF;
        end
        else begin
            
        end
    end
```

But, I'm getting errors on this line:

```
product <= product_FF;
```

It says:

> Error: mult32x32_arith.sv(19): Illegal assignment to type 'reg[63:0]' from type 'reg $[63:0]': Cannot assign an unpacked type to
> a packed type.

But, I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `product` as packed and `product_FF` as unpacked.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.4 *Packed and unpacked arrays*:

> The term *packed array* is used to refer to the dimensions declared
> before the data identifier name. The term *unpacked array* is used to
> refer to the dimensions declared after the data identifier name

You need to declare them as the same data type.  For example, to make them both packed, change:

```
logic left_decoder, right_decoder, product_FF[63:0]={64{1'b0}};
```

to:

```
logic left_decoder, right_decoder;
logic [63:0] product_FF = {64{1'b0}};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution: bitstream cast - see Section 6.24.1 in the [language specification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

`typedef logic[63:0] packed_64;`

and then the assignment

`product <= packed_64'(product_FF);`

Maybe the typedef is unnecessary, haven't tested it.