# cannot assign a packed type to an unpacked type

Tags: vhdl, simulation, system-verilog, vivado

I have a mixed simulation with the Vivado 2022.1 simulator:

using a VHDL library I should not change (mytypes.vhd):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package mytypes is

  type std_logic_vector_array is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;

  type my_record is record
    rxdata      : std_logic_vector_array(3 downto 0)(7 downto 0);
  end record;
end package mytypes;
```

and the testbench in system-verilog (mytest.sv):

```
import mytypes::*;

class MyPacket;
  rand bit[31:0] _header;
endclass 

module simu(
    output mytypes::my_record recdata
   );

  logic CLK100;
  MyPacket pckt;
  const int increment = 2;
  
  initial
  begin
    CLK100 = 0;
    forever #(5) CLK100 = ~CLK100;
  end

  initial
  begin
    pckt = new();
    pckt.randomize();
    @(posedge CLK100); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i+= increment) begin
      recdata.rxdata[0][7:0] = pckt._header[i*8 +: 8]; //https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865519/9963147
      //some stuff ignored here for the example
      @(posedge CLK100); //output header
    end    
  end
endmodule
```

I get the followin error from the simulator: `[VRFC 10-395] cannot assign a packed type to an unpacked type`

I know about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477764/illegal-assignment-cannot-assign-an-unpacked-type-to-a-packed-type), but

- this is a mixed-source simulation
- changing the VHDL package is not an option + VHDL does not have packed-unpacked datatypes
- declaring the MyPacket._header as unpacked seems unlogical/unreasonable, because it is one logical element

Is there a way to tell the simulator to interpret the VHDL array as packed? Or is there a macro or something similar to work around this issue? It just does not seem reasonable to change my data model in order to please a dumb simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is something called bitstream cast (Section 6.24.1 in the [language specification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595))

This way the simulator does not complain:

```
import mytypes::*;

class MyPacket;
  rand bit[31:0] _header;
endclass 

typedef logic unpacked_byte[7:0];

module simu(
    output mytypes::my_record recdata
   );

  logic CLK100;
  MyPacket pckt;
  const int increment = 2;
  
  initial
  begin
    CLK100 = 0;
    forever #(5) CLK100 = ~CLK100;
  end

  initial
  begin
    pckt = new();
    pckt.randomize();
    @(posedge CLK100); 
  
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i+= increment) begin
      recdata.rxdata[0][7:0] = unpacked_byte'(pckt._header[i*8 +: 8]); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/33865519/9963147
      //some stuff ignored here for the example
      @(posedge CLK100); //output header
    end    
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Inter-language interface support is not defined by either language or any other standard. Hence what is/is not supported between language is tool dependent, and you will have to consult the manuals of all tools (or FAEs etc) to determine what is supported.

Comment: UG900 (v2023.2) User Guide: Logic Simulation Appendix J Vivado Simulator Mixed Language Support and Language Exceptions "All those types that are supported as VHDL port (listed in Table 50: Supported VHDL and Verilog Data Types) are also supported as a record element." A Note following the table which is quite restrictive on record element types making this almost a one trick pony. The issue here is as Tricky alludes portability. A particular VHDL implementation's record declaration is not guaranteed to match a SV packed array. VHDL doesn't define underlying machine type representation.